# What made many of the coding websites converting standard " into non standard ”?

Tags: encoding, smart-quotes

This question is about standard double quote **"** and non-standard double quote  **“** &  **”**

Yesterday when I searched for some sample facebook serverfbml codes, and came upon to this

http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/11/22/facebook-fbml-rendering-in-iframe-application/

okay so it has got what I want, so I copied the code to my project and run it...  bah... lots of errors

Why? Because the site turned the standard double quote " inside his script into  **“** or  **”** ,
or single quote from ' into **’**

This is not the first time I faced this problem when copying codes from the Internet, and I believe many of the code writers haven't expected that the site turned their single/double quotes into strange ones.

Any explanation to this strange phenomenon ?

edited: I notice the title converted my " into **“** &  **”** too... let me edit it... oh and I failed

Comment: RSS feed contains the original double quotes in the title

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least in the title or in the text, it looks much better to have typographic double quotes (i.e. is more pleasant to the eye). Coding sites *should* not do this for actual code, i.e. in StackOverflow code that is indented by four spaces. If a double quote in text is converted to typographic, it's fine.

This gets really worse when you paste typographic quotes into a console that *tries to display the character and falls back to a standard quote, because the console font does not have a typographic quote*. Because then it looks like it's a standard one, but it isn't. Not much you can do about it, other than use a code display plugin on your website that does not change code.

Comment: "Because then it looks like it's a standard one, but it isn't."  omg ;p

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the underlying blog engine. Wordpress does that by default, and there is AFAIK no way to turn it off (Without [changing the code](http://codeleet.hub.ph/disable-wordpress-curly-quotes/)). Given the fact that there are only relatively few really great blog engines, there may not always be a choice to switch to something "better".

Also in the same category: Fancy dashes, aka. turning - into –

Answer (score 0):

the source shows that the quote char is sometimes &#8221;
that's the quote that is the good looking quote which will cause problem in a program.

i think either the WordPress text editor or storage/retrieval converted the ordinary quote into that one.

You can use the replace function in your program editor to replace those characters.